# what are these permissions used for

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-manifest

in android manifest code these permissions are used sometimes.for what these are used?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

thanks

Comment: check my answer given below.....hope this information is enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic Android application has no permissions associated with it, meaning it **can not do anything** that would adversely impact the user experience or any data on the device. **`To make use of protected features of the device, you must include in your AndroidManifest.xml one or more <uses-permission> tags declaring the permissions that your application needs`**.

**`Refer these links for more info.:`**

[**1. Security article at Android Developer Page**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html)  and

[**2. For All the permission List**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

and

`When you install an application from the Android Market`, **it will tell you all of the permissions it needs to function**. These are important to read as it can give you an idea if the application is asking for permission to do more than it needs. While some legitimate apps often ask for more permission than they need, it should at least raise an eyebrow when deciding if an application is safe and of good quality.

Answer (score 1):

Most of them are pretty self-explanatory, don't you think?

Is there anything more in detail you are wondering about?

There's a short description of them [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Comment: The explanation for ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS is "Allows an application to access extra location provider commands". That's not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

They are access permissions. `android.permission.CAMERA` dictates whether an application can use the camera,  `android.permission.VIBRATE` dictates whether an application can use the vibrator, etc.

Full explanation at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).